# How to get 2 strings between certain characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

String:

```
echo "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran"
```

I want to grab everything before the first instance of | and everything between External_SOC and ;PCRF. And store them as 2 different variables if possible.

```
x=40125512
y=ALPHA3
```

This gives me the following:

```
sed -e 's/|.*External_SOC=\(.*\);PCRF.*/\1/'
```

40125512ALPHA3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP it needs to be done in a single line creation 2 of variables if this is the case then try following.

```
read -r x y <<<$(echo "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran" | sed 's/\([^|]*\).*=\([^;]*\).*/\1 \2/')
echo "$x"
40125512
echo "$y"
ALPHA3
```

OR use following as per anubhav sir's comment:

```
read x y < <(sed -E 's~^([^|]+)\|.*External_SOC=(.+);PCRF.*~\1 \2~' <<< "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran")
```

---

---

Could you please try following. One could use it from 2 separate commands to create 2 separate variables.

```
x=$(echo "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran" | sed 's/\([^|]*\).*/\1/')
echo "$x"
40125512

y=$(echo "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran" | sed 's/.*=\([^;]*\).*/\1/')
echo "$y"
ALPHA3
```

Comment: This works, but is it possible to do it in one line? because i am feeding in from a sqlite3 statement.
```
sqlite3 database.db 'SELECT SOC_CD,SOC_PROPERTIES FROM CSM_OFFER;' | sed -e 's/|.*External_SOC=\(.*\);PCRF.*/\1/' > out1.txt
```

Comment: @ineedLINUXhELP, Ok try my EDIT code now and let me know then?

Comment: `read x y < <(sed -E 's~^([^|]+)\|.*External_SOC=(.+);PCRF.*~\1 \2~' <<< "40125512|abcd32External_SOC=ALPHA3;PCRFabcran")` is better than using `<<<` and pipeline.

Comment: @anubhava, Sure sir, added it too now, Thanks for letting know sir, cheers.